# Site-wide CustomValidator methods.

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I have a web form that uses CustomValidators, and I have a few validation routines in my "validators.js" file that I can set as the `ClientValidationFunction` on each `CustomValidator`. Routines such as ValidateRequired, ValidateEmail, ValidateUsername etc.

I would like to define a set of globally available CustomValidator functions within my c# code itself, however I'm failing to grasp how to do this.

The ideal solution would be something along these lines:

**Validators.cs:**

```
protected void ValidateUsername(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e){
   // Validation Logic here
}
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtUsername">
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" OnServerValidate="ValidateUsername" id="cvldUsername" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUsername"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

I know I could probably add the event into my default.aspx.cs which then calls my Validation function for a bool response and then return a true/false on IsValid -- But I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this.

I feel I may be missing something.

Thanks in advance,

Dave